# Is there a way to check post to 1 url or the other in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently proxying my session creation url with express in a way like this:

```
app.post('/sessions', (req, res) => {
  // Logic here
})
```

Logic that goes into this proxy also repeats for my `/confirmation` endpoint, hence I would not want to rewrite it instead I'd want above `app.post(...` to also check for my second url, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.post.method) for `app.post`

> The path for which the middleware function is invoked; can be any of:
>
> - A string representing a path.
> - A path pattern.
> - A regular expression pattern to match paths.
> - **An array of combinations of any of the above**.

which means you can actually pass in an array of paths

```
app.post(['/sessions', '/confirmation'] , (req, res) => {
    // Logic here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like that:

```
function myLogic(req, res) {
  // Logic here
}

app.post('/sessions', myLogic);

app.post('/confirmation', myLogic);
```

Here there are [official examples](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#path-examples) of routes definitions.

Answer (score 0):

just use a callback then:

```
function handler(req, res) {
  // Logic
}

app.post('/sessions', handler);
app.post('/confirmation', handler);
```